Using images in HTML with webpack 5
I'm trying to use img in HTML tag:
<img src="./img/author.jpg" alt="The photo of the author" />

with webpack configured like this:
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    filename: "./img/[name][ext]", 
  },
},

I use img folder stored directly in src dir, Webpack copies my image correctly to dir, but when I try to display it, it won't show and I get GET error:

GET http://localhost:8081/img/author.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I was trying to change the location on the image but it didn't help

The leading dot might make it relative? Try: "/img/[name][ext]" instead.
